# How to prevent injection attack in CREATE query in python mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql-injection

I know the proper way to avoid injection attack in SELECT or INSERT queries using python module MySQLdb is:

`cursor.execute("SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM breakfast WHERE price < %s", (max_price,))`

However, when I tried to apply the same rule in CREATE query it returns error. My code:

`cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE %s;", ("test",))`

It reports syntax error:

`_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test'' at line 1")`

It seems it is because the query adds single quote to the db name and Mysql does not allow that in CREATE query?

So what is the proper way to CREATE database or table using python MySQLdb module then, given the db name or table name is not fixed?

Comment: Do you really need a parameterized query for this?  It's somewhat unusual to be creating entire tables/databases based on user-provided data.

Comment: Just append the string: `cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE " + "test")`

Comment: @hjpotter92: Well, or just use one string in the first place: `cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE test")`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `cursor.execute("SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM breakfast WHERE price < %s" % (max_price,))` isn't injection-safe. That builds a query string containing the text of `max_price` and then passes it to the cursor.

Comment: @BrenBam yeah so generally the code needs to receive database name and create it on the go.

Comment: @user2357112 well since that is the way the API is built so I figured they will have some sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

Try square brackets;

```
cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE %s;", ["test"])
```